# Generate every permutation of list elements pairs without repeating or inverted pairs

Tags: python

I know this is similar to previous questions but there are enough differences in my request to merit a new question. I have a list of string elements.

```
>>> mainlist
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

I want to create a looped program that takes the first element and then pairs it with the remaining elements like so:

```
['one two', 'one three', 'one four', 'one five']
```

Notice it did not create the pair `'one one'`

The next cycle should be:

```
['two three', 'two, four', 'two five']
```

Notice, again, it did not create `'two two'` or even `'two one'` as, for my purposes, this is equal to `'one two'`.

and so on...

The nearest I've got is:

```
for primary in mainlist:
    for secondary in mainlist:
        if primary == secondary: print("skipping...")
        else: print(primary + " " + secondary)


>> skipping...
one two
one three
one four
one five
two one
skipping...
two three
two four
two five
three one
three two
skipping...
three four
three five
four one
four two
four three
skipping...
four five
five one
five two
five three
five four
skipping...
```

Based on the above you can see that this doesn't quite match what I'm after. Any help would be really appreciated - I'm sure there's an elegant solution out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested for loops using the indices should do the trick:

```
for i in range(len(mainlist)):
    for j in range(i,len(mainlist)):
        if mainlist[j] == mainlist[i]:
            print 'Skipping'
        else:
            print mainlist[i] + ' ' + mainlist[j]
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll use this as it's the easiest to implement in my existing code

Answer (score 16):

You want to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
In [1]: import itertools as it

In [2]:  mainlist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

In [3]: for a,b in it.combinations(mainlist, 2):
   ...:     print(a, b)
   ...:     
one two
one three
one four
one five
two three
two four
two five
three four
three five
four five
```

In the same way you could also create all possible triplets from the same by specifying `3` as second argument:

```
In [4]: for a,b,c in it.combinations(mainlist, 3):
   ...:     print(a, b,c)
   ...:     
one two three
one two four
one two five
one three four
one three five
one four five
two three four
two three five
two four five
three four five
```

If you want to produce also the pairs `one one`, `two two` etc. you should use [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) instead.

---

If you want to group together the pairs with the same first element you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [1]: import itertools as it
   ...: mainlist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
   ...: 

In [2]: for key, group in it.groupby(it.combinations(mainlist, 2), key=lambda x:x[0]):
   ...:     print('key is', key)
   ...:     print('grouped elements', list(group))
key is one
grouped elements [('one', 'two'), ('one', 'three'), ('one', 'four'), ('one', 'five')]
key is two
grouped elements [('two', 'three'), ('two', 'four'), ('two', 'five')]
key is three
grouped elements [('three', 'four'), ('three', 'five')]
key is four
grouped elements [('four', 'five')]
```

---

Finally, if you want to write the loops explicitly you can use `enumerate` to keep track of your current index:

```
In [3]: for i, el in enumerate(mainlist):
   ...:     for el2 in mainlist[i+1:]:
   ...:         print(el, el2)
   ...:         
one two
one three
one four
one five
two three
two four
two five
three four
three five
four five
```

This is basically what `combinations` does, except that it works with arbitrary sizes (pairs, triplets etc)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use nested `for` loops:

```
>>> mainlist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>> for e in mainlist:
    for i in mainlist:
        if e == i:
            print "Skipping"
        else:
            print e, i


Skipping
one two
one three
one four
one five
two one
Skipping
two three
two four
two five
three one
three two
Skipping
three four
three five
four one
four two
four three
Skipping
four five
five one
five two
five three
five four
Skipping
>>>
```

Comment: This unfortunately produces inverted pairs eg. 'one two' and 'two one' so no good.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

for i in range(len(l)):
    print ["{} {}".format(l[i], l[j]) for j in range(i + 1, len(l))]
```

Or you can explore the endless possibilities of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) as suggested by @Bakuriu.

**output**

```
['one two', 'one three', 'one four', 'one five']
['two three', 'two four', 'two five']
['three four', 'three five']
['four five']
[]
```

Comment: Thanks, list indices is what I needed!

Comment: @Beeman You're welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as helpful or accepted if you want to reward me :-)

Comment: Hi, I had to mark the answer that I went with as the accepted one - despite yours and others being equally useful, sorry. Also I don't have enough rep to mark yours as helpful but when I do I shall